# Is there a "Comprehensive conTeXt Symbol List"

Tags: symbols, context, documentation

I'm used to use [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) for my LaTeX document  to search for a specific symbol, many of them are defined with a package.

My aim is to find documents which list symbols but in `conTeXt` and how can I insert them in my document

Comment: In principle you don't need it.  ConTeXt MkIV builds on LuaTeX and supports Unicode math input, so basically you could type `\starttext $∀X [ ∅ ∉ X ⇒ ∃f:X ⟶  ⋃ X\ ∀A ∈ X (f(A) ∈ A ) ]$ \stoptext` ([output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BnpPo.png)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a curated list similar to Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol list, but you can generate various automated lists to show all the characters in a font.

1. Run

   ```
   context --global --bodyfont=modern s-math-characters.mkiv
   ```

   This generates a 137 page document. Here is a snippet

   [image]

   `mathname` is the name of the macro that will give you the symbol. As you can see, this document also shows how the symbol will be composed if the font does not have that symbol, and whether a symbol is extendable or not.
2. Run

   ```
   context --global s-math-repertoire.mkiv --once
   ```

   which generates a 2068(!) page document showing how each symbol looks in different fonts. Here is one page showing the arrow in different fonts:

   [image]

As @Henri Menke said, you can also typeset in Unicode math; if you know the unicode symbol and just want to search for the corresponding symbol name, grepping `char-def.lua` file is quicker.